# ReactJS Access Existing Variables?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, minify

I am building a ReactJS app. On the page where the React Component is going to live, there is an existing JS Object that I would like React to have access to.

Due to the magnification process of `npm run-scripts build`, I am not able to access the variable by name. Is there a way to do this without having to make a rest API call?

I have tried using the lifecycle event of `componentDidMount` to access the JS object and push it into state, but it complains that it can't find it. If I define the object with dummy data in the React app, I can see that it is still referring to the dummy data in React (via console.log in componentDidMount). If I use the JavaScript console in Chrome, I can see that the value is the NEW value. Is this a problem because React runs inside it's own container, and it doesn't have access to existing JS objects?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

**UPDATE**

My limitation is my server side framework. I am currently REQUIRED to use ASP.Net WebForms. I have created an `<asp:Literal` items in the page, and I update the value of this with the the JS Object.

This is what my Basic React App looks like.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

/* THIS WILL  BE POPLATED BY C# */
var EntityObject = { Person: { FirstName: 'Foo', LastName: 'Bar' }};

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      name: 'DEFAULT'
    }
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.state);
    this.setState({name: EntityObject.Person.FirstName + ' ' + EntityObject.Person.LastName })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">{this.state.name}</h1>
        </header>
        <p className="App-intro">
          To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

C# Code Looks something like this

```
string sample = @"EntityObject = { Person: { FirstName: 'Test', LastName: 'User' } }";
<asp:Literal ID="jsContainer" runat="server">
jsContainer.Value = "<script>" + sample + "</script>";
```

Comment: We need to see some code before we can give you any suggestions, the current question text is way to broad.

Comment: why don't you just require your object ?

Comment: on top of your component write const yourObject = require("./yourObjectLocation"); in your js file module.exports = Object

Comment: I have updated my code example.

Comment: Is there a better way to go about this?